# How to Simulate a Transaction Without Balance?

Tags: web3js

I'm trying to make a honeypot detector by simulating a transaction and checking if slippage is less than 45%. But I can only do this if I have a balance of the token I specifically want to transfer/trade.

Is there a way around this using web3 or ethers?

Comment: I'm not sure if i got the question correct. but "for testing" you can fork the network with hardhat and then use `hardhat_impersonateAccount` to impersonate an account which have tokens and make the transaction